# How do I protect connection string passwords in powershell?

Tags: powershell, security, systemmanagement

I want to be able to securely operate on an IIS website's connection strings using PowerShell. How can I do this safely? I do not want to expose any password information. For example, does the following script have any concerns if you were a security expert?

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$destination = 'NewSql'
$sitePath = 'Default Web Site'
$connectionStringList = ( get-webconfiguration $sitePath -filter "connectionStrings/add" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ).Where( { $_.connectionString -match 'Initial Catalog *=|Database *=' } )

foreach($string in $connectionStringList){
   $cs = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder $string.connectionString -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($null -ne $cs)
    {
        Copy-DbaDatabase -Source $cs.DataSource -Destination $destination -Database $cs.InitialCatalog
    }
}
```